# How to insert element to specific position in the structure array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to insert a new structure in the structure array at the position i. Now I do it using horzcat:

```
temp1 = arr(1:(i-1));
temp2 = arr(i:arrsize);
arr = horzcat(temp1, new_element, temp2);
```

Is there any way to make it faster? The size of the array is usually about 500 structures.

Comment: you could use `arr = [temp1,new_element,temp2]`

Comment: if you want faster you should consider cellarray instead of struct array. Matlab stores its arrays **contiguously** in memory, therefore, inserting an element to an array (no matter where) usually incur copying of the entire array to a new location.

Comment: Cell array wouldn't be convenient. The thing is I don't need to actually store all structures in order, I just need to be able to quickly access the first element. If I just store the order in the seperate field and look for the first one every time, won't it be faster?

Comment: @EvgeniiNikitin if you have a fixed number of elements and all you want is to re-arrange them, then it is better to use an additional index array on which you do the order manipulations.

Comment: No, this is more like a priority queue. I add new elements according to the certain rule, and I also remove the first element from this queue.